# VueJS - Delete all components

Tags: javascript, ajax, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a nested table that loads data dynamically. When the user click on the "+", an ajax request was made and the result was render by a recursive component.

I know that is not very clear, you can take an example on this fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/rafi16d/whsbLn59/.

When the user click again on the "filter" button, I want to delete all the components "row-item" and render the new result from ajax request.

I've been searching for but I doesn't find anything about removing multiple components.

Has anyone run into anything similar?

Thank

Comment: That happens automatically; it's just how Vue works. When you change the underlying data, the DOM will be updated to match. You should add a [`key` attribute](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#key) though.

Comment: Thanks ! It's works ! I've added the key attribute and Vue automatically update the children and remove rows if there is no children.